# allowClear config for rallyusercombobox is doing nothing

Tags: javascript, rally

I have added a config, setting the [allowClear attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoo0k.png) to true. However, this change does not reflect in my app. [The box still does not display a clear text option,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asDf4.png) even though my console tells me that the config was indeed
[changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifCvN.png) Is it apparent where my error is?

Comment: This very well may be a defect.  If you also add allowNoEntry: true does it work then?